# Where do I get PEM encoded Private Keys and and DER encoded Certificate paths on Mac?

Tags: swift, macos, encryption, swift-package-manager, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to use the new SPM Collection signing utility found at https://github.com/apple/swift-package-collection-generator/tree/main/Sources/PackageCollectionSigner

But I honestly don't know how to get the necessary files.

Here is the definition:

```
USAGE: package-collection-sign <input-path> <output-path> <private-key-path> [<cert-chain-paths> ...] [--verbose]

ARGUMENTS:
  <input-path>            The path to the package collection file to be signed
  <output-path>           The path to write the signed package collection to
  <private-key-path>      The path to certificate's private key (PEM encoded)
  <cert-chain-paths>      Paths to all certificates (DER encoded) in the chain. The certificate used for signing must be first and the root
                          certificate last.
```

I understand the input-path and output-paths arguments but where do I get the PEM encoded private key and the DER encoded path chains?

Sorry if I am being naive, but this is just an area I have no experience with.

Any help about how I get/generate these files would be helpful.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The private key you can generate yourself on the command line

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
chmod 600 private.pem
```

Once you have the key, you will need to request a certificate that uses it. This can also be done on the command line:

```
openssl req -new -key private.pem -out signing.csr
```

Once you have that, you can go to developer.apple.com and click on the "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" section, then click on the "Certificates" tab. Click the blue plus button, choose the "Swift Package Collection Certificate" option and click Continue.

It will ask you to upload a CSR, so click Choose File and select the `signing.csr` file you just created. Download the generated certificate and rename it to `signing.cer` and you should be ready to go.

*Once you're done this, you can delete the `signing.csr` file.

Comment: Thank you. i will give that all a try.